# What trigonometry identity is used to get this result?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

[image: picture]

Okay, I understood they split $\cos^4t$ in half but I don't know what was used to get $1/4$ out in front and the $4$ in front of $\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$.

Comment: Associativity of scalar multiplication and linearity of the integral.

Comment: The $3$ was brought out of the integral, then a $\frac{1}{4}$ was also added to the outside, requiring that the inside be multiplied by $4$. Think of it like this: on the outside you multiplied by a clever form of $1$, in this case $\frac{4}{4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note that](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_factor_rule_in_integration):
$$\int_a^b c\cdot f(t) ~dt\equiv c \int_a^b f(t)~dt\tag{1}$$
Therefore:
$$\int_0^{\pi} 3\sin^2 t \cos^4 t ~dt=3\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2 t \cos^4 t ~dt$$
You can now divide the outside of the integral by $4$ while multiplying the inside, it is a consequence of $(1)$, since you are essentially multiplying by $\frac{4}{4}$:
$$3\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2 t \cos^4 t ~dt=\frac{3}{4}\int_0^{\pi} 4\sin^2 t \cos^4 t~dt$$
Now, note that:
$$\cos^4 t\equiv\cos^2 t\cdot \cos^2 t$$
And that scalar multiplication is [associative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property):
$$(a\cdot b)\cdot c\equiv a\cdot (b\cdot c)$$
Therefore, we obtain the expression you need.

Comment: But why was 4 chosen? Is it because it would easily fit the identity?

Comment: @cout Are you asking why I chose to use $4$, or why they used $4$ in the identity you were given? If you are asking why I chose to use it, it is simply because it would fit the identity.